# is it possible to create an array of more than one datatype in java If possible, how?

Tags: java, arrays, list

I want to create an array like the list ones like the ones in python3 in java but I don't know how to do it
Ex: {"John", 1, True, 1.7}

Is it possible to create an array of more than one datatype in java
If it is possible, how is it done?

Comment: That is a `set` in Python. Even in Python, although lists can hold arbitrary objects, generally it is good practice to make them homogeneous

Comment: Well you can create an `Object[]` if that's what you want...

Comment: Comparing Java and Python in this regards makes no sense. Python is a dynamically typed language, while Java is statically typed. Anyway, we could use an `Object[]`, I would however strongly advice against that.

Comment: You could define an object which has fields of different types.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to create an array of more than one datatype in java If it is possible

No, not possible. But you're mistaken - in python, this is also impossible.

The trick is, in Python all objects are just 'object', and you have a list of objects. In java, expressions do have a type. Nevertheless, all objects are, well, objects. So:

```
Object[] o = {"John", 1, true, 1.7};
```

works. You really don't want this - arrays are low level constructs. You'd want `List<Object> o = List.of("John", 1, true, 1.7};` no doubt.

Also, why do you want to store this in a list? It SOUNDS like you want this:

```
class Person {
    String name;
    int id;
    boolean enrolled;
    double gpa;
}
```

and then a `List<Person>`. That is 'the java way'. Junking that stuff in an `Object[]` is **not** the java way. When in rome, act like romans. When coding java, write it like java people would. If you do not, anybody else can't read your code, and libraries do not work for you or feel weird and unwieldy. If you insist on programming 'python style', then just use python.

Comment: I feel this answer contains more "rant" than "answer".

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I do not hear the ranting. To my ears, this Answer is all good advice.

Comment: Le bonheur des uns fait le malheur des autres :-)

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

Use records in Java 16 and later.

```
record Person ( String name , int talentCode , boolean isAvailable , double grading ) {}
```

## Tuple

Given your example of `{"John", 1, True, 1.7}`, I suspect you have a set of properties related to a single entity rather than a collection of siblings. In other words, you have [tuple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple).

### Class

If this is case, such as all four of those values describing a single person, then in Java we would create a class named `Person` to hold four member fields. Each field would be of the appropriate type.

```java
package work.basil.example.recs;

import java.util.Objects;

public final class Person
{
    private final String name;
    private final int talentCode;
    private final boolean isAvailable;
    private final double grading;

    public Person ( String name , int talentCode , boolean isAvailable , double grading )
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.talentCode = talentCode;
        this.isAvailable = isAvailable;
        this.grading = grading;
    }

    public String name ( ) { return name; }

    public int talentCode ( ) { return talentCode; }

    public boolean isAvailable ( ) { return isAvailable; }

    public double grading ( ) { return grading; }

    @Override
    public boolean equals ( Object obj )
    {
        if ( obj == this ) return true;
        if ( obj == null || obj.getClass() != this.getClass() ) return false;
        var that = ( Person ) obj;
        return Objects.equals( this.name , that.name ) &&
                this.talentCode == that.talentCode &&
                this.isAvailable == that.isAvailable &&
                Double.doubleToLongBits( this.grading ) == Double.doubleToLongBits( that.grading );
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode ( )
    {
        return Objects.hash( name , talentCode , isAvailable , grading );
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return "Person[" +
                "name=" + name + ", " +
                "talentCode=" + talentCode + ", " +
                "isAvailable=" + isAvailable + ", " +
                "grading=" + grading + ']';
    }
}
```

Using this class.

```java
Person alice = new Person( "Alice" , 1 , true , 1.7 ) ;
System.out.println( alice.getName() ) ;
```

> Alice

### `record`

Writing such a class is much easier in [Java 16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_16), if the main purpose of such a class is to transparently and [immutably](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) hold this data.

The new [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) feature lets us define a class briefly, declaring the member fields only. The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

Records can be thought of as *nominal tuples*, to quote JEP 395. The “nominal” means each value is named, and “tuple” means a finite ordered sequence of values.

```java
public record Person ( String name , int talentCode , boolean isAvailable , double grading )
{
}
```

Using this record.

```java
Person alice = new Person( "Alice" , 1 , true , 1.7 ) ;
System.out.println( alice.name() ) ;
```

> Alice

A record can be written as a separate class, nested within another class, and can even be defined locally within a method.